# Knockout Validations for Select

Tags: jquery, validation, knockout.js

I have a few select controls and input boxes in my form which are mandatory fields and I am using Knockout Validations to validate them. I would like for the controls to be highlighted (using errorElementClass)on submit or when modified. Unfortunately, my select controls are highlighted when the page is first loaded itself.

```
<div>Names
    <select data-bind="options: allNames, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'name', value: names, optionsCaption:'Select Names'"></select>
    <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</div>

            ko.validation.configure({
            insertMessages: false,
            messagesOnModified: true,
            decorateElement: true,
            errorElementClass: "input-validation-error",
            deep: false,
            enableErrorDetails: true
        });

        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.names = ko.observable("").extend({
                required: true
            });
            self.allNames = new ko.observableArray([]);

            self.call = function () {
                self.allNames.push({
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Adam"
                });
                self.allNames.push({
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Bert"
                });
                self.allNames.push({
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Keith"
                });
                self.allNames.push({
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Anna"
                });
                self.allNames.push({
                    id: 5,
                    name: "Andie"
                });
            }
        }
        self.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
        vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.call();


        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        });
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

CSS

```
.input-validation-error {
border-color:red !important;
border-style:solid !important;
border-width:1Px !important;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px red !important;
/*Add webkit box shadows for other browsers*/
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/ppPVc/2/

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: I've modified my question and I hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I will take a look at it but for future reference it is 100x more helpful when you can show a simplified fiddle with the problem showing to help understand and debug faster, just FYI

Comment: I edited my question and added a fiddle. I basically would like the element to be highlighted on submit and not on page load. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you don't want to apply the CSS until submit is pressed?

Comment: I basically want the validation (CSS and any errors I decide to display.) to kick in when it is modified or submitted.  It works perfectly on input boxes but not on select controls.

Comment: Just FYI the problem is because the value is empty when you are using a placeholder like that but your validation is 'required'.  I am playing with it give me one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed it to the following:

self.names = ko.observable(undefined).extend({
                required: true
            });